# Are there primary source to learn about trade in Southeast Asia circa 1450-1750?

Tags: sources, early-modern, south-east-asia

I was wondering if anyone knew any primary sources that will help me learn more about trade in Southeast Asia from 1450-1750. Years are a bit flexible.

I only have two in mind

*The Suma Oriental* by Tome Pires
*Selections from Le Quy Don's Descriptions of the South in the 1770s*

If you know any please give me the link and name of the source

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I do have a list. I wonder if you have a specific topic, location or language in mind? It doesn't need to be but it helps narrow the focus, even if just for compiling it.